# Add circle to Smith chart using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using the Smithchart library with PGF/TikZ, and I'm trying to add a simple circle in the middle of the chart.
However, the circle is plotted using the "smithchart coordinate system" so it looks flatted out.

Code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{smithchart}
            \draw (1,0) circle[radius=0.5];
        \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Imgur]

I tried digging into the PGFplots manual but found nothing similar.

Comment: Do you need the circle for highlighting a particular point, or is the size of the circle meaningful in terms of the axis units?

Comment: The size is meaningful. For example, I would like to draw the circle in which the arc crossing the x-axis at 1 is in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `5.10 Smith Charts` of pgfplots manual, there are many examples and notes about your question.

Please note that by changing `\path[draw=red] (0pt,0pt) circle (1.5cm);` to `\path[draw=red] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);` you can use the smith's coordinates instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{smithchart}
        \path[draw=red] (0pt,0pt) circle (1.5cm);
        \path[draw=blue] (0.2,0.5) circle (0.75cm);
        \path[draw=blue,fill=blue] (0.2,0.5) circle (0.05cm);
        \end{smithchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I would like to plot circle for SWR = 1.5 similiar to yours like
`\path[draw=blue] (0,0) circle (1.5);` with no `cm` handling? Is it possible too?

Comment: Doesn't work. The coordinates are plotted in the wrong coordinate system. Drawing a circle in the middle of the chart requires me to write the coordinate (0,0) and not (1,0).